# Get page URL parameters from a service worker

Tags: javascript, url, service-worker, url-parameters, url-parsing

How do I get page URL with parameters from a service worker?

I have tried `self.registration.scope` but that doesn't include the parameters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm not clear as to whether you're asking about getting the service worker script's URL, or the URLs of all of the client pages that are open under the service worker's scope. So... here's how to do both:

```
// Get a URL object for the service worker script's location.
const swScriptUrl = new URL(self.location);

// Get URL objects for each client's location.
self.clients.matchAll({includeUncontrolled: true}).then(clients => {
  for (const client of clients) {
    const clientUrl = new URL(client.url);
  }
});
```

In either of those cases, once you have a `URL` object, you can use its [`searchParams` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams) if you're interested in the query parameters:

```
if (url.searchParams.get('key') === 'value') {
  // Do something if the URL contains key=value as a query parameter.
}
```

Comment: The sample code that I provided that calls `self.clients.matchAll()` will allow you to get the URLs of all the open pages that are in scope of the current service worker.

Comment: My bad, I misread that, the first approach is clearly to get the script's location. Deleting my comment to avoid any further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `waiting.scriptURL` or `active.scriptURL`, pass result to `URL()` constructor, get `.search` property of object

```
  navigator.serviceWorker.register("sw.js?abc=123")
  .then(function(reg) {
    const scriptURL = reg.waiting && reg.waiting.scriptURL || reg.active.scriptURL;
    const url =  new URL(scriptURL);
    const queryString = url.search;
    console.log(queryString);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log("err", err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[ServiceWorker.scriptURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorker/scriptURL) can give you the URL and its parameters as well.

Then, the following step is to get a `ServiceWorker` object, and it depends on where you would like to use the URL parameters.

In the worker script, use `self.serviceWorker.scriptURL`. e.g.

```js
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(self.serviceWorker.scriptURL);
```

In the page script, use `scriptURL` with `navigator.serviceWorker.ready`. e.g.

```js
const serviceWorkerRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
const activeServiceWorker = serviceWorkerRegistration.active;  
const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(activeServiceWorker.scriptURL);
```

However, you might want to get a registration object from `register` API, but the above code snippet should work as well.